# Magento2 outdated issues

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I am creating a docker container for magento2. Made everything ready and  now I am getting this error from the running container.

> Previously had an permission issue fixed by changing the permission
>   for directory required, than I got his error.

I tried this ***./bin/magento setup:upgrade*** but didn't solve the problem.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Directory db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.1, currently installed - 2.0.2
Magento_Directory db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.1, currently installed - 2.0.2
Magento_Catalog db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.2.3, currently installed - 2.2.4
Magento_Catalog db data version: defined in codebase - 2.2.3, currently installed - 2.2.4
Magento_Sales db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.7, currently installed - 2.0.9
Magento_Sales db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.7, currently installed - 2.0.9

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Directory db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.1, currently installed - 2.0.2
Magento_Directory db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.1, currently installed - 2.0.2
Magento_Catalog db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.2.3, currently installed - 2.2.4
Magento_Catalog db data version: defined in codebase - 2.2.3, currently installed - 2.2.4
Magento_Sales db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.7, currently installed - 2.0.9
Magento_Sales db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.7, currently installed - 2.0.9
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#9 {main}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is poor error messaging on the part of Magento

```
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Directory db schema version: 
    defined in codebase - 2.0.1, currently installed - 2.0.2
```

A better error message might have been "your system database is configured with modules ahead of those in your codebase.

Somehow, the module.xml files on your system.

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/module.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_Directory" setup_version="2.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Store"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

have one version number, but the data in the setup table in MySQL (or cached values read from this table)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM setup_module WHERE module = 'Magento_Directory';
+-------------------+----------------+--------------+
| module            | schema_version | data_version |
+-------------------+----------------+--------------+
| Magento_Directory | 2.0.2          | 2.0.2        |
+-------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Somehow you've updated your system with one set of module files, but the system you're actually serving your files from is still an older one.

Comment: What might be the better solutions

Comment: This is a really good answer Alan, do you believe therefore you should go through the database and manually change it

Comment: Alan, you're normally a lot more helpful, but you haven't provided any assistance here, only info.  If we've gotten ourselves into this strange situation, how do we fix it?  Nothing I can find online is helping.  It won't install something it thinks is older, but the DB got messed up...so what's the fix?

Comment: @BrianVPS Investigate the circumstances that allowed for a mismatch in versions and take appropriate steps to fix whatever problem that is.  General advice to fix this isn't possible based on the information given.

Comment: @AlanStorm I don't tend to use composer for my installs, but when I do, it's usually frustrating.  In the most recent case, I did a `composer require abc/xyz`, and that resulted in it downgrading a ton of core modules.  I have no idea why, I still don't understand this issue.  I then did `composer upgrade` and it brought them back up to current.  This may be me not understanding how composer works, it's not something I used in the past.  But the fact that it's so easy to accidentally ruin your code is a bit problematic...